# Dosage Prediction

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data-science, prediction

I have a medical research dataset. Here I have some disease related parameters, so I have to predict a dose which will bring these parameters in normal range. How to approach such problems.

Let's say X, Y, Z (disease related parameters) is at 100, 20, 5 now, normal range is 0 to 4, 5 to 10 and 0.5 to 2 respectively. So I want to predict a dose that X, Y and Z will come to normal range after taking that dose.

How to approach such problems?

Thanks in advance.